# How to undo 'git add -A' and 'git init', but still keep subfolders in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-stage, git-init

I mistakenly ran 'git init' followed by 'git add -A' on a main folder (named "workspace").  I intended to 'cd' down into a new project folder (named "authentication") before running these commands.

The issue is, this main folder "workspace" *already* had numerous project subfolders that were individually in Git beforehand.  The main folder was not previously under Git, nor ever meant to be. Fortunately, I have NOT ran 'git commit' on the main folder.

How do I safely reverse the 'git add -A' on the main folder, as well as revert the 'git init' command on the main folder, **WITHOUT affecting all the subfolder projects** that are to remain individually under version control (Git)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main folder `workspace` was not under Git before, just delete the folder `workspace/.git`:

```
rm -r workspace/.git
```

If it was under Git, `git init` will have pretty much no effect. The opposite action of `add` is `reset`:

```
git reset
```

Comment: Yes I'll clarify, the main folder was not under Git before.  I have updated my original comments to make this more clear.

Comment: Then just remove the directory `workspace/.git` that `git init` created, and you will be sorted.

Comment: This command didn't seem to work for me.  Here's what I got:             
rm: cannot remove ‘workspace/.git’: No such file or directory

Comment: if you go in the `workspace` directory, and run `git status`, what do you get?

Comment: So I get `On branch master
No commits yet
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)`.  Then it lists `new file:` followed by all the folder projects I've created and nothing else.

Comment: so from here, run `rm -r .git` to remove the `.git` directory. If you have none here, it means you ran the `git init .` in some parent directory.

Comment: To be certain, this command `rm -r .git` (instead of `workspace/.git`) will not remove git from all the subfolders, if I understand correctly?

Comment: It will remove just the directory you pass in argument (`.git`), not any subdirectories

Comment: I might add, these folders are all on Cloud9.  But I wouldn't think that would affect the use of it's terminal or the commands in Git.

Comment: Ok this seems to have worked. I will say it prompted a LOT of lines wanting a 'y' or 'n' response, which was rather intimidating.  First line was: `rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘.git/objects/91/`….(then lots of letters & numbers). After typing a 'y' then enter, it prompted another similar line: `rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘.git/objects/fe/`....(then another set of letters and numbers.)  I then typed 'n' for this and the next 20 or so similar prompts!  Not sure what all that was asking about.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rm
You can use `rm -rf .git` to delete the whole directory without confirmation. You want it all deleted.

Answer (score 0):

`git init` probably did nothing.

I would run a `git status` to see all of the files you added with your `git add -A` command and "unadd" the files you no longer want there by running `git reset [filename]`